# How can I make my CSS menu's hover states move horizontally for UX purposes?

Tags: html, css

How can I make my menu's hover state "red fade" move horizontally in natural motion (like the example in the image)?

This is my menu I made in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xcRGR/2/) to try and learn how to get the movement down. I'm trying to emulate how http://www.fullyillustrated.com/ menu when its hover state works the blue bar follows the mouse to the next link and the image of the nav bar image posted below.

[image: From Smashing Magazines Smart Transitions UX article]

```
#menu {
   background: #181818;
   height: 120px;
   width: 500px;
}
#menu .center {
   display: table;
   height: 120px;
   width: 500px;
}
#menu ul.menu-center {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
#menu ul li {
   display: inline;
}
#menu li a {
   color: #FFF;
   padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
   height: 120px;
}
#menu li a:hover {
   background: red;
   transition: .25s linear;
   -webit-transition: .25s linear;
   -moz-transition: .25s linear;
   padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're trying to achieve has to be done with Javascript...just to make sure I know what you're asking:

- You have a bar that when you hover over a link in your navigation, it animates to the active anchor and is the same size as the anchor.

Here's the fiddle I created to demonstrate what I think you're asking:

http://jsfiddle.net/Dm9Eu/2/

If you take a look at your browser's web inspector when you visit Fully Illustrated, you'll see that the navigation has a gutter element that contains a span#highlight that is the full width of the navigation ul that contains the anchors.

When you hover over an anchor, the left position changes of the span#highlight.

You could use javascript to setup a function that on hover, get the left position of the anchor, set that position on span#highlight and using css3 you could set transition to 'left', and it should emulate your desired effect.

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="gutter">
    <span id="highlight"></span>
</div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    position: relative;
}
#menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background: #181818;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
#menu li a {
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 50px;
    display: block;
}

#highlight {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 5px;
    background: #f00;
    transition: all .5s;
}
```

JS:

var doc = document;

```
var anchors = doc.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('a');
var highlight = doc.getElementById('highlight');

for(var i = 0, len = anchors.length; i < len; i++) {
    anchors[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
        var target = e.target;
        highlight.style.width = target.offsetWidth + 'px';
        highlight.style.left = target.offsetLeft + 'px';
    });

    anchors[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
        var target = e.target;
        var storeNeg = '-' + highlight.style.width;
        console.log(storeNeg);
        highlight.style.left = storeNeg;
    });
}
```

Just a few notes:

- I did this with vanilla JS, so if you're concerned with browser compatibility, you might use a library like jQuery <= 1.9.
- I would inject the gutter on the page with js, because if js is disabled, no need in having it.

Hope that helps/answers your question!

Comment: Thanks! I thought you could do this via CSS3 only, so thanks a lot. And sorry for a late reply. My internet went down last night and just came back up.

Comment: Hi "chaseadamsio", how to give active to it?

Comment: @Kiran are you asking how to apply an active class to the element?

Comment: any one to help me in finding this

Comment: Inside of the `mouseover` event  `target.className += " active";` and in `mouseout` `target.className.replace(/ active/, '');`

Is that what you're asking for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I've exactly answered the question but, here goes:

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xcRGR/4/

```
#menu li a {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 50px 0 50px 0; <- amended
  margin: 0 50px 0 50px; <- New
  display: inline-block; <- NEW
}
#menu li a:hover {
  background: red;
  transition: .25s linear;
  -webit-transition: .25s linear;
  -moz-transition: .25s linear;
  padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px; <- amended
  margin: 0; <- NEW
  width: auto;
}
```

I've basically added some margin on the buttons, changed the padding to horizontal rather than vertical and transitioned the margin as well so the reduction in margin (horizontal) is taken up by the increase in padding.